# Do I annotate and EJB if its not published with RESTful interface?

Tags: web-applications, ejb, resteasy

If I am using an EJB internally with a web application using RESTeasy 2.1 do I need to annotate the interface as described in [this document](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.1.GA/userguide/html/RESTEasy_EJB_Integration.html)?

It seems as thought [the document](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.1.GA/userguide/html/RESTEasy_EJB_Integration.html) is showing how to configure an EJB to be published publicly - accessible via a URL.

When I use the annotation described in [the document](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.1.GA/userguide/html/RESTEasy_EJB_Integration.html) I get this error:

```
14:01:50,294 ERROR [STDERR] 1979 [main] INFO org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ConfigurationBootstrap - Adding scanned resource: com.ccorp.report.ejb3.TestBean
14:01:50,457 ERROR [[/ReportAPI]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Test not bound
```

I have RESTeasy scan enabled and have also configured my web.xml file with this added;

```
   <context-param>
      <param-name>resteasy.jndi.resources</param-name>
      <param-value>Test/String</param-value>
   </context-param>
```

Any ideas are very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this answer I gave on another post:  [Accessing @Local Session Bean from an exposed RESTeasy interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813898/resteasy-w-ejbs-aaaarrrrgh#answer-5827873)