#  Accessing @Local Session Bean from an exposed RESTeasy interface

Tags: ejb, resteasy

What I am trying to do should be very straight forward BUT thus far has been impossible. Can someone tell me how to access a @Local Session Bean from an exposed RESTeasy interface? I have trawled the length and breadth of the internet and all I can find is variations of the same example

I am trying to find out how I can access a session bean in the normal way using RESTeasy. This is what things look like so far:

USING:

> EJB 3
>
> RESTeasy 2.1

PUBLISHED EJB INTERFACE:

```
@Local
@Path("RequestReport")
public interface EReport {
 
     @GET
     @Produces({"application/xml"})
     @Path("request")
     public String requestReport(@QueryParam("reportId") @DefaultValue("") String reportId,
                                 @QueryParam("reportName") @DefaultValue("") String reportName, 
                                 @QueryParam("reportType") @DefaultValue("") String reportType);
 
     }
}
```

BEAN 1:

```
@Stateless
public class EReportRequest implements EReport {      
         
     @EJB 
     private ReplyStringLocal replyString; // THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM LIES.
 
     public String requestReport(@QueryParam("reportId") @DefaultValue("") String reportId,
                                 @QueryParam("reportName") @DefaultValue("") String reportName, 
                                 @QueryParam("reportType") @DefaultValue("") String reportType) {     
 
          return replyString.getReply(reportId, reportName, reportType);        
 
    }
}
```

UNPUBLISHED EJB INTERFACE:

```
@Local
public interface ReplyStringLocal { 
 
     public String getReply(String reportId, String reportName, String reportType);
 
}
```

BEAN 2:

```
@Stateless
public class ReplyString implements ReplyStringLocal { 
 
     public String getReply(String reportId, String reportName, String reportType) {
 
          return "<response><reportId>" + reportId + "</reportId><reportName>" + reportName +
                 "</reportName><reportType>" + reportType + "</reportType></response>";
      } 
}
```

This example is super simplified for the purposes of demonstrating my issue. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*For: JBoss 5, RESTeasy 2.1 and EJB 3.*

Ok so I finally got the full story on EJBs with RESTeasy. So here it is:

> **A. You can publish a Session bean with a RESTful interface by giving it RESTeasy path annotation and EJB Session bean annotaion.**

*INTERFACE:*

```
@Local
@Path("MessageMaker")
public interface MessageMakerLocal {

    @GET
    @Produces({"application/xml"})
    @Path("getMessage")
    public String getMessage(@QueryParam("message") @DefaultValue("") String message);

}
```

*IMPLEMENTATION:*

```
@Stateless
public class MessageMakerImpl implements MessageMakerLocal {

    public String getMessage(@QueryParam("message") @DefaultValue("") String message) {
        return "Your Message: " + message;
    }
}
```

.

> **B. You cannot use @EJB annotation in RESTeasy so using a @Local Session bean reference from a published POJO or published EJB is out of the question. So the example provided in the original post is not valid.**

.

> **C. To access a Session Bean from published POJOs or published Session Bean, you can use the @Remote interface annotation and JAR your Bean classes. When you are building your EAR file add the JAR to the root of your EAR and add a reference to it in your META-INF/application.xml file.**

*INTERFACE:*

```
@Remote
public interface MessageMakerRemote {

    public String getMessage(@QueryParam("message") @DefaultValue("") String message);

    }
}
```

*IMPLEMENTATION:*

```
@Stateless
@RemoteBinding(jndiBinding = "MessageMakerRemote")
public class MessageMakerImpl implements MessageMakerRemote {

    public String getMessage(String message) {
        return "Your Message: " + message;
    }
}
```

*In Application.xml:*

```
<module>
    <java>MessageMaker.jar</java>
</module>
```

You can then make reference to it using a JNDI remote call to your jar:

```
@Local
@Path("Message")
public class Message {

    @GET
    @Path("requestMessage")
    public String requestMessage(@QueryParam("msg") @DefaultValue("") String msg){

        // I use a custom JNDI remote call handler class so my call to the JARed beans looks like this:
        return JNDIRemote.getRemote(com.message.ejb3.MessageMakerRemote.class).getMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

I am hoping that later versions of RESTeasy will provide better integration of EJBs.